# CSS property "inline" is not giving me a new line in web page

Tags: html, css, inline

In `.manager-record-header` and `.manager-record` I've added property `display: block;`, I expect it to create a new line for each `<div>` I type as `manager-record-header` or `manager-record`. Somehow it's not working - Item 01 and Item 02 appear in the same line. Where could be the problem?

this is my web page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
  <style type="text/css">
h1 {
    font: bold 1em 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Sans-serif;
    color: #333;
  font-size: 1.5em; color: #6297BC;
}
h1 {  } 

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font: 11px/1.6em  Verdana, Tahoma, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #666666; 
    background: #A9BAC3;
    text-align: center;
}

#manager-body {
    background: #FFF;
    width: 820px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    text-align: left;
}

.manager-record-header  {
  font-size: 2em;
  padding-left: 15px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.manager-record-header-name {
  padding-left: 5px;
  width: 350px;
  float:left;
}

.manager-record-header-quantity {
  width: 100px;
  float:left;
}

.manager-record  {
  padding-left: 15px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.manager-record-title {
  float:left;
  padding-left: 5px;
  width: 350px;
}

.manager-record-quantity {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
}

</style>
 </head>
<body>
<div id="manager-body">
<h1>Item pricing</h1>

    <div class="manager-record-header">
      <span class="manager-record-header-name">Item name</span>
      <span class="manager-record-header-quantity">Quantity</span>
      <span class="manager-record-quantity">Price</span>
    </div>
    <div class="manager-record">
      <span class="manager-record-title">Item 01</span>
      <span class="manager-record-quantity">10</span>
    </div>
    <div class="manager-record">
      <span class="manager-record-title">Item 02</span>
      <span class="manager-record-quantity">3</span>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think the issue comes from the `floating` stuff

Comment: Have a [JS Fiddle demo of the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9acxD/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fiddle of your problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/YQQHc/

This looks like data that would be best presented in a `table`.  I say forget the `div`s and use a table.

**EDIT**

Something like this

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <td>Item name</td>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td>Price</td>            
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Item 01</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item 02</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>?</td>
    </tr>        
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/YQQHc/1/

Answer (score 1):

As @Nico said the problem comes from floating the contents of the divs, which means that the divs are not presentationally containing the spans.

Easily fixable by adding `overflow:hidden` to `.manager-record-header` and `.manager-record`.

But I agree with @Jason Gennaro. This looks like tabular data to me.

Comment: Ok, I'll use a table. Thanks everyone for your input.